# Flutter header file alternative

Tags: flutter, dart

In C/C++ there are header files that allow us to use functions from many files with only one #include. I was wondering if there was something similar that I could use in Dart.

For example, let's say I have this file structure:

```
lib
├── widgets
│   ├── appbar.dart
│   ├── drawer.dart
│   └── list.dart
└── main.dart
```

In my main.dart I don't want to have 3 imports, if I were to make more widgets it would be inconvenient to add. I just want to import something like another file called `widgets.dart` that would allow me to use the widgets from the other files.

In C++ we would do something like this:

```
#ifndef WIDGETS
#define WIDGETS

#include "widgets/appbar.cpp"
#include "widgets/drawer.cpp"
#include "widgets/list.cpp"

AppBarWidget(string title);
DrawerWidget();
ListWidget();

#endif
```

With this I would be able to use the widgets from all those files just by including the header file, and I was wondering if there was an easy way to implement this for Dart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a widget.dart file that uses the export keyword on those widget files, you can then use import widget.dart to make them accessible.

More info: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages